# AngularJS: call factory from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using following link for using requirejs with angularjs 
https://github.com/StarterSquad/startersquad.github.com/tree/master/examples/angularjs-requirejs-2

how can i use service function which is defined in js\services\version.js

i have following code in services.

```
 services.factory('Phone', ['$resource',
    function($resource){
        console.log("factory");
    }]);
```

i want to call this factory function in controller. how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to register your service in " angular.module(); "

```
app.controller('myController',['Phone','$scope',function(Phone,$scope){
  //your code here
}]);
```

Answer (score 4):

Just add the factory in your controller.

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope, Phone){           

});
```

Comment: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $resourceProvider <- $resource <- Phone

Comment: Did you load the ngResource script and added it as an dependency in your app?

Comment: I believe this answer is the right approach.  It is not obvious to me from the question if the factory is created on the same module that the controller is created on.  Assuming that 'services' is the name of the module, then replace app with services.

Comment: @PriyaBhatt please read [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

Comment: thanks for the link. it is bit confusing to use angular with require. i am using following link to integrate angular with require but i dont know how to use services.factory with following link https://github.com/StarterSquad/startersquad.github.com/tree/master/examples/angularjs-requirejs-2